# Switch off search highlighting in gVim

Tags: vim, gvim

When I do search in gVim (package gnome-vim), the search results are highlighted. How can I turn-off this highlighting when I don't need it any longer? Now it looks like persistent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable search results highlighting by command `:nohl`. If you want to have this command under one keystroke, put the following lines into your `~/.vimrc` configuration file:

```
" press F8 to turn the search results highlight off
noremap <F8> :nohl<CR>
inoremap <F8> <C-o>:nohl<CR>
```

Now you can press <kbd>F8</kbd> to toggle search result highlighting on and off in both edit and insert mode.

Comment: +1, but wouldn't `inoremap <F8> <C-o>:nohl<CR>` be better? So it will leave you in the same input mode where you were...

Comment: @Rmano please explain. My solution (it is taken from my own ~/.vimrc) doesn't change the editor mode.

Comment: CTRL-o is the command to enter in normal mode for just one command, and then go back to input. In your macro, you exit input mode, and the you do an "append". So for example if you are inserting *before* the first caracter of a line (go to the start of the line and press "i"), with your macro after pressing F8 you will be inserting *after* the first character of the row (the result of "a"). With my version you will just continue inserting before or after, whatever you were doing before pressing F8.

Comment: @Rmano You are right, I just tried your 'test scenario' and it works like you said. Thanks for pointing this out, I will update my ~/.vimrc as well as my answer here.

Comment: For the record this cannot turn highlighting back on. This only turns highlighting off (temporarily). The next search will highlight again automatically though.

Answer (score 3):

You can edit your `.vimrc` file :

To disable the highlighting temporarily, write `:set nohlsearch` and delete `:set hlsearch`

Then **save** and **exit** .